# Functions from cmath generate run-time infinite loop (No such file or directory)

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I am writing a program for class that reads in a set of ordered pairs from a file and implements the k-means algorithm to identify data clusters. This involves the use of the distance formula, which requires the calculation of a square root. As such, I have included the cmath library, and used the sqrt() function, and everything compiles correctly. However, at run-time, the program generates an infinite loop, which I have determined in gdb is caused by the use of the sqrt function, which causes gdb to generate the line "w_sqrt.c: No such file or directory." I have a similar unresolved problem with the rand() function from the cstdlib library, however I am unable to replicate it until the sqrt() problem is resolved.

Note: This is my first time posting a question on StackOverflow so I apologize in advance if I have overlooked any conventions or rule of posting here.

Additional note: Please limit feedback to that directly related to the problem I have described above. For reasons of academic honesty, I am not seeking advice on the implementation of the k-means function, I am simply trying to get the program to run so that, if there are further problems, I can identify and solve them myself.

Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

const int ARRAY_MAX = 1000;
//DECIMAL_MULT = 10^(required number of decimal places)
const int DECIMAL_MULT = 10000;

struct node{
    double xVal;
    double yVal;
    char symbol;
    int clusterIndex;
};

//Returns the distance between the two input nodes
double getDistance(node A, node B) {
    double xSquare = ((B.xVal - A.xVal) * (B.xVal - A.xVal));
    double ySquare = ((B.yVal - A.yVal) * (B.yVal - A.yVal));
    double result = sqrt(xSquare + ySquare);
    return result;
}

int main(){
    int numNodes = 0;
    char temp[ARRAY_MAX];
    string filename;
    ifstream file;
    cout << "Enter the name of the file to be read: ";
    getline(cin, filename);
    file.open(filename.c_str());
    //Check the number of data entries present in the file
    while (!(file.eof())) {
        numNodes++;
        file.getline(temp, ARRAY_MAX);
    }
    numNodes--;
    file.close();
    node list[numNodes];
    file.open(filename.c_str());
    //Build a list of data points
    double xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;
    double value;
    file >> value;
    file.ignore();
    xMin = value;
    xMax = value;
    list[0].xVal = value;
    file >> value;
    file.ignore();
    yMin = value;
    yMax = value;
    list[0].yVal = value;
    for (int i = 1; i < numNodes; i++) {
        file >> value;
        file.ignore();
        list[i].xVal = value;
        if (value < xMin) (xMin = value);
        if (value > xMax) (xMax = value);
        file >> value;
        file.ignore();
        list[i].yVal = value;
        if (value < yMin) (yMin = value);
        if (value > yMax) (yMax = value);
    }
    //Prompt user for number of clusters and symbol to be used for each
    int numClusters;
    cout << "Please enter the number of clusters to be analyzed: ";
    cin >> numClusters;
    cin.ignore();
    node centerList[numClusters];
    char usedSymbols[numClusters];
    char entry;
    bool validEntry;
    for (int i = 0; i < numClusters; i++) {
        centerList[i].clusterIndex = i;
        do {
            validEntry = true;
            cout << "Please enter the character representing "
                << "cluster " << i + 1 << ": ";
            cin >> entry;
            cin.ignore();
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (centerList[j].symbol == entry){
                    cout << "Character has already been "
                        << "used.\n";
                    validEntry = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while (!validEntry);
        centerList[i].symbol = entry;
    }
    //Assign random starting points to cluster centers
    srand(time(NULL));
    int xMaxCast = xMax * DECIMAL_MULT;
    int xMinCast = xMin * DECIMAL_MULT;
    int yMaxCast = yMax * DECIMAL_MULT;
    int yMinCast = yMin * DECIMAL_MULT;
    int xRange = xMaxCast - xMinCast;
    int yRange = yMaxCast - yMinCast;
    int randValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < numClusters; i++) {
        randValue = std::rand() % xRange + xMinCast;
        centerList[i].xVal = randValue / DECIMAL_MULT;
        randValue = std::rand() % yRange + yMinCast;
        centerList[i].yVal = randValue / DECIMAL_MULT;
    }
    //Determine the cluster of each node
    for (int i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {
        list[i].clusterIndex = centerList[0].clusterIndex;
        for (int j = 1; j < numClusters; j++) {
            if (getDistance(list[i], centerList[list[i].clusterIndex])
                > getDistance(list[i], centerList[j])) {
                list[i].clusterIndex = j;
            }
        }
        list[i].symbol = centerList[list[i].clusterIndex].symbol;
    }
    bool proceed = true;
    double average;
    int clusterCount;
    while (proceed) {
        proceed = false;
        //Move each cluster center to the centroid of its currently
        //  assigned points; if all centers are already in the
        //  correct positions, discontinue this operation
        for (int i = 0; i < numClusters; i++) {
            average = 0;
            clusterCount = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < numNodes; j++) {
                if (list[j].clusterIndex == i) {
                    average += list[j].xVal;
                    clusterCount++;
                }
            }
            average /= clusterCount;
            if (centerList[i].xVal != average) {
                proceed = true;
                centerList[i].xVal = average;
            }
            average = 0;
            clusterCount = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < numNodes; j++) {
                if (list[j].clusterIndex == i) {
                    average += list[j].yVal;
                    clusterCount++;
                }
            }
            average /= clusterCount;
            if (centerList[i].yVal != average) {
                proceed = true;
                centerList[i].yVal = average;
            }

        }
        if (proceed) {
            //Update cluster assignment of each node
            for (int i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < numClusters; j++) {
                    if (getDistance(list[i],
                    centerList[list[i].clusterIndex])
                    > getDistance(list[i],
                    centerList[j])) {
                        list[i].clusterIndex = j;
                    }
                }
                list[i].symbol =
                centerList[list[i].clusterIndex].symbol;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused.  Does the code actually compile and run or do you get compilation/linker errors?

Comment: The code compiles and starts to run, however it does not run to completion, as it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Far too much code. You should learn how to create a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in an expression like `centerList[i].xVal != average` (i.e., an int is not equal to a double), both values will be compared as doubles.  This ends up being a terrible way of comparing floating point numbers, and this is widely discussed.

But here's where the real problem happens. `centerList[i].xVal = average;` does not assign `centerList[i].xVal` to `average` but `(int) average` (the nearest integer to `average` towards zero).  This leads to a condition that is infinitely repeated.  If `node::xVal` and `node::yVal` were doubles or the not-equals comparison was fixed by comparing integers or the not-equals comparison was fixed by appropriately comparing floating point numbers, then the program will likely not loop indefinitely (it did not loop indefinitely for the input that I tried).

Note that using the flag `-Wconversion`, warnings for `centerList[i].xVal = average;` and `centerList[i].yVal = average;` appear. Additionally, `-Wconversion` is not covered by either `-Wall` or `-Wextra`.  I have found that `-Wconversion` is a worthwhile flag to use when developing code for numerical algorithms even though it may produce many seemingly benign warnings.  Everything is fine and dandy until a devastating implicit conversion from a `float` to an `int` causes a massive relative error.

I would hypothesize that `gdb` indicated `sqrt` when you inserted a break point because `sqrt` is relatively expensive and called frequently.  `gdb` simply couldn't find the source for `sqrt` (maybe because the source isn't installed on your system).

Comment: I did embarrassingly notice that I had accidentally typed xVal and yVal as ints when they should have been doubles. This has been corrected, although I do have other errors to work out, which I now understand to not be related to sqrt. So thank you for that part. I can't imagine that anyone in particular would benefit from my not deleting this question. But that warning message when I go to do so is quite ominous. Should I ignore that and delete it anyway or leave it as is?

Comment: Leave it as is for now.  Someone will come along and close it if they believe it should.

Comment: Today I learned the importance of casting conversions. double a = int / int will produce an int value for a. a = (double) int / (double) int will produce a double value. If anyone comes to this page for some reason, check your conversions.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with `sqrt`. The only infinite loop I see is that `proceed` constantly becomes `true`. This in turn happens because comparing doubles for equality is at best dubious.

It could be due to implementation errors (I am not fluent in clustering to find them); it may very well be due to rounding errors.

Since you already using a debugger, step through the `while(proceed)` loop and see how `average` behaves. Depending on it, you need either revisit the algorithm, or allow for a tolerance when comparing.

Comment: Because there are a finite number of data points entered, there should be a finite number of average values that can be calculated. And because the center is being assigned the exact same value that was calculated in each iteration of the loop, it should reach a point where no points need to be assigned to a new center, and therefore the location of the centers doesn't change, which is the purpose of the algorithm. At least, that is my thought process. Am I mistaken? Also, are you saying that the debugger message about the missing directory is normal? I'm just clarifying, not contradicting.

Comment: The center is not being assigned the exact same value.

Comment: @R.Williams The debugger message is only saying that you don't have source code for the math library (it is normal and expected). And I have no say about the algorithm.